# Angular Reactive Froms to a Date

Tags: angular

I need to make a validator that checks that a date is not greater than the current day and less than 30 days

```
validarPagoFormulario(){
  this.pagoForm = this.formBuilder.group({fecha_pago: ["", Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.min(Date.now)])],
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a function to count the number of days between two `Date`

```
numDaysBetween(date) {
  let now = new Date() //today's date
  var diff = Math.abs(date.getTime() - now.getTime());
  return diff / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);  //divide by how many MS in a day since date.GetTime() returns MS value of a date
};
```

Then we can come up with a condition like

```
//assume date is a already defined Date object
let daysBetween = numDaysBetween(date)
if (daysBetween >= 0 && daysBetween <= 30){
    // do something if the date is after today and less 30 days old
}
```

Then you can use this function to add to your Validators

Comment: and how would I add it to the Validators ?

Comment: that part should be pretty straight forward in your use case and the documentation could explain it better than I could found here: https://angular.io/api/forms/Validators